# Построение микросервисов - правильное распределение сервисов

Tags: архитектура, микросервисы

У меня есть проект - вакансии. Есть набор скиллов ( sql,c# и т.д.) вокруг которого крутится проект. Я пишу на микросервисах и хочу их правильно разбить, но не знаю как, так как опыта мало. У меня есть вакансии, в которых есть подробная инфа, а так же набор необходимых скиллов. Так же у пользователя есть профиль, в котором есть резюме, где так же указаны этот набор скиллов. В будущем будет снова подвязка на этих скиллах, например, курсы и т.д. Я думал сделать сервис для скиллов - их CRUD. Сделать сервис вакансий - там юудет инфа о вакансии, а так же список  id этих скиллов из другого бд. Для профиля отдельный сервис, где так же будет набор id скиллов.При удалении скилла, я буду использовать kafka, которая будет оповещать об этом. И например из вакансии этот скилл удалится. Правильно ли это вообще? И правильно ли хранить только id скилла. Ведь мне надо будет для каждого id обращаться в другой микросервис для получения информации. Или же лучше хранить id + title. Но тогда придется также отслеживать изменение информации в Скиллах и оповещать другие  сервисы.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: что правильно, а что нет - очень сильно зависит от задачи и требований. Чисто из вашего описания я бы задался вопросом - зачем там вообще нужны микросервисы?

Comment: @tym32167 я больше для себя этот проект делаю, чтобы выучить микросервисную архитектуру. Возможно не самый удачный пример, так как все завязано на одном сервисе со скилами. Но  все же интересно как это организовать

Comment: ну вот у вас какая задача? Сделать систему, где существуют вакансии и резюме кандидатов, чтобы их можно было сопоставлять. По мне, так это единая система, пока не доказано обраное. Вот какой смысл их разделять? Особенно учитывая, что сопоставление делать гораздо проще, если и то и это в одном сервисе находится. Если у вас есть какая то веская причина разделить эти вещи - тогда другой разговор, а пока что разделение разди разделения - так в микросервисах не делается. Если мы будем плодить сервисы на каждый чих, то стоимость итоговой системы будет космичнской.

Comment: это вы еще не дошли до того, что вакансия будет в какую то компанию, и профиль будет с опытом работы в каких то компаниях. Вакансия потребует определенного уровня владения разными продуктами (типа 5 лет Кафки), и профиль будет про Х лет владения продуктами\инструментами. В вакансии могут требоваться какие то сертификаты, и в профиле могут быть сертификаты. В вакансии может требоваться наличие диплома\автомобиля\курсов массажа, и в профиле та же самая фигня. По большому счету, вакансия - это собирательный профиль идеального кандидата.